# Angular route not firing at all

Tags: angularjs

I triggered the `%a{"ng-click"=>"get_destinations(city)"}`

However, it should redirect me to "destinations" controller, but it didn't

and there is no error in webconsole, what's going on ?

## welcome.js.erb

```
  var App = angular.module('App', ['ngRoute']);

  App.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/depart_from/:id',
      {
        templateUrl: "<%= asset_path('promotion_destinations.html') %> ",
        controller: 'destinations'
      }
    )
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/depart_from/:id' });
  }]);

  App.controller("departure_cities", function($scope, $location, $http) {
      $http.get("/promotion.json")
      .success(function (response) {
        $scope.departure_cities = response;
      });
      $scope.get_destinations = function(id) {
            return $location.url("/depart_from/" + id);
      };
  });

  App.controller("destinations", function($scope, $location, $http) {
      $http.get("/another_city.json")
      .success(function (response) {
        $scope.destinations = response;
      });
  });
```

Comment: If you add console.log in your `$scope.get_destinations` function does it log at all?

Answer (score 2):

Your default controller is **destinations** in the **$scope** of destinations controller no any method like **get_destinations** .
Put your method in side **destinations** controller it will work if every thing is fine.

Comment: Hi,I think your were misunderstanding. I was calling the `get_destinations` in `departure_cities ` controller, and tried to invoke the route `'/depart_from/:id'`

Comment: inject `$state` in controller after that use `$state.go('depart_from',{'id':id})`

you not define `url` in your `config`

Answer (score 1):

Well if you can link the html generated (the one that see the browser, not the server template) that would help.

However i still see an error for me in the HTML (or it's a naming problem)

```
 get_destinations(city)
```

And in the javascript :

```
$scope.get_destinations = function(id)
```

Maybe you wanted to do this ?

```
  get_destinations(city.id)
```